# QuickFix C++: Errors when compiling Acceptor

Tags: c++, quickfix, algorithmic-trading, fix-protocol

## Goal:

To compile the "Acceptor" program (server). When this is complete, to then compile an "initiator" (client) to then print a simple output to confirm that the two applications are communicating with each other (the requirements of which I have read through the QuickFix documentation and mostly understand).

**Please note** before posting this question, the QuickFix mailing list and SO have been consulted. A question with similar issues can be found at the following URL, however, the answers are still causing me some confusion:
[Compiling a quickfix program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358675/compiling-a-quickfix-program%3E)

## Problem:

When attempting to compile the following sample **Acceptor** program exactly copied from http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/application.html, various errors have been appearing, as seen further below. The compilation command I used was:

```
g++ trade_server_test.cpp -std=c++11 -fexceptions -finline-functions -lquickfix -lpthread -lxml2
```

The program:

```
#include "quickfix/FileStore.h"
#include "quickfix/FileLog.h"
#include "quickfix/SocketAcceptor.h"
#include "quickfix/Session.h"
#include "quickfix/SessionSettings.h"
#include "quickfix/Application.h"

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    try
    {
        if(argc < 2) return 1;
        std::string fileName = argv[1];

        FIX::SessionSettings settings(fileName);

        MyApplication application;
        FIX::FileStoreFactory storeFactory(settings);
        FIX::FileLogFactory logFactory(settings);
        FIX::SocketAcceptor acceptor
          (application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory /*optional*/);
        acceptor.start();
        // while( condition == true ) { do something; }
        acceptor.stop();
        return 0;
    }
    catch(FIX::ConfigError& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

## Error Outputs

The following errors are observed:

```
trade_server_test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
trade_server_test.cpp:17:3: error: ‘MyApplication’ was not declared in this scope
   MyApplication application;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
trade_server_test.cpp:21:6: error: ‘application’ was not declared in this scope
     (application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory /*optional*/);
```

I then modified the object name from `"MyApplication"` to `"Application"`, and received the following error outputs. The "Application" class is defined in the header file `Application.h`. The compiler recognizes all of the included header files, so I am confused as to why it is saying "Application" is not declared in this scope.

```
trade_server_test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
trade_server_test.cpp:17:3: error: ‘Application’ was not declared in this scope
   Application application;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~
trade_server_test.cpp:17:3: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/local/include/quickfix/Acceptor.h:29:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/quickfix/SocketAcceptor.h:29,
                 from trade_server_test.cpp:3:
/usr/local/include/quickfix/Application.h:43:7: note:   ‘FIX::Application’
 class Application
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
trade_server_test.cpp:21:6: error: ‘application’ was not declared in this scope
     (application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory /*optional*/);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Changing the object again from `"Application"`to `"FIX::NullApplication"` gets rid of the above errors, but then a new error appears:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have successfully downloaded and built `QuickFix 1.15.1` on `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` and have been able to run some of the example applications e.g. `OrderMatch` and `TradeClient` (although with only partial functionality) by following this procedure:

```
% tar xvzf quickfix-1.15.1.tar.gz
% cd quickfix
% ./bootstrap
% ./configure
% make
% sudo make install
```

## Summary Questions

1. How can I successfully compile the sample **Acceptor** program on `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` for `QuickFix 1.15.1`? A step-by-step guide would be highly appreciated in terms of which libraries to link, header files to compile with which flags etc.
2. Does the command for compilation seem correct?
3. Should any of the header files be compiled alongside this application (although I thought these would have been compiled when `make` was ran during the `building` process?

Comment: For the xml2 error, you need to install the libxml2-dev package or equivalent on your distribution.

Comment: The sample code is indeed showing you how to hook up a custom subclass of `FIX::Application`, you are expected to create that subclass.

Comment: As for your third question : no header files should not be compiled separately. They are included when cpp files are compiled.

Comment: (those comments should really be an answer, sorry)

Comment: Hi @Botje , thanks for your help and no problem about the comments. Would you elaborate on your comment regarding me creating a subclass? From the documentation, it seems that the class/subclass are already created in "quickfix/application.h"... do I need to create a new header file? Apologies if my wording is inaccurate, I’ve been stuck on this issue for some time.

Comment: The Application abstract class is declared in that header, yes. You need to provide a concrete implementation, such as the NullApplication you found. If these concepts are not familiar, take some time to read a good C++ OO tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a subclass of Application yourself.
Let us look at the declaration of Application:

```
namespace FIX
{
  class Application
  {
  public:
    virtual ~Application() {};
    virtual void onCreate( const SessionID& ) = 0;
    virtual void onLogon( const SessionID& ) = 0;
    virtual void onLogout( const SessionID& ) = 0;
    virtual void toAdmin( Message&, const SessionID& ) = 0;
    virtual void toApp( Message&, const SessionID& )
      throw( DoNotSend ) = 0;
    virtual void fromAdmin( const Message&, const SessionID& )
      throw( FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon ) = 0;
    virtual void fromApp( const Message&, const SessionID& )
      throw( FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType ) = 0;
  };
}
```

All these methods marked with `= 0` are pure virtual functions: they have no implementation and you cannot instantiate `FIX::Application` directly. Instead you have to declare a subclass. *Where* you do this does not matter, as long as the declaration is in scope at the moment you create your `MyApplication` instance. This can be either in the same file or in a header file you included.

A simple subclass of Application that does nothing might look like the following:

```
class MyApplication : public FIX::Application
{
  void onCreate( const SessionID& ) { std::cout << "onCreate" << std::endl; }
  void onLogon( const SessionID& ) { std::cout << "onLogon" << std::endl; }
  void onLogout( const SessionID& ) { std::cout << "onLogout" << std::endl; }
  void toAdmin( Message&, const SessionID& ) { std::cout << "toAdmin" << std::endl; }
  void toApp( Message&, const SessionID& ) throw( DoNotSend ) { std::cout << "toApp" << std::endl; }
  void fromAdmin( const Message&, const SessionID& ) throw( FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, RejectLogon ) { std::cout << "fromAdmin" << std::endl; }
  void fromApp( const Message&, const SessionID& ) throw( FieldNotFound, IncorrectDataFormat, IncorrectTagValue, UnsupportedMessageType ) { std::cout << "fromApp" << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed answer, this has completely solved my issue. Thank you for taking the time to provide such a well-structured explanation- everything is now working as expected.